# add new column with matching id in both Table 1 and Table 2

Tags: sql, join, case

I have two tables, 
in table1 I have 5 rows and 
in table2 3 rows

table1:

```
#no---Name---value
1-----John---100
2-----Cooper-200
3-----Mil----300
4-----Key----200
5-----Van----300
```

Table 2:

```
#MemID-#no---FavID  
19-----1-----2   
21-----1-----3
22-----2-----5
```

Now expected result:

```
#no---name---value---MyFav
1-----John---100-----NULL
2-----Cooper-200-----1
3-----Mil----300-----1
4-----Key----200-----NULL
5-----Van----300-----NULL
```

1 indicates - My favorites
MyFav - new column ( alias)
This is the expected result, please suggest how to get it.

Comment: Can you explain why `Cooper` and `Mil` alone got `1` in Myfav column

Comment: you should explain what you expect to get in your output result ! No logic could be found out of it by looking at It

Comment: John wants to know his favorites,  whom he marked as his Favorites in table 2

Comment: @Chennoju . . . Perhaps the logic for getting the `MyFav` column is obvious to you, but it is not at all clear to someone who has no understanding of your data or your problem.  More explanation is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the logic.  You want `MyFav` to be marked as a `1` if that row is a favorite of John.  You can do this with a `left join` and some more filtering:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when t2.#no is not null then 1 end) as MyFav
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.#no = t2.FavId and
        t2.#no = (select tt1.#no from table1 tt1 where tt1.Name = 'John');
```

Comment: @Chennoju - then you need to mark it as answer. Select the **tick mark** to the left of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use natural join for that, It will use your primary key as a mediator to join both the tables, as required. In your case, I think primary key is `#no`

---

For more information on natural join please visit [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: select * from table1 + select * from table2 where #no = 1 , the returned FavID should be marked in table 1 data by adding any alias column

Comment: But I prefer join so because JOIN Operation is performed by the database and I Think that it would be better in terms of efficiency, and it does also allows to make it easier for us to create other table

Comment: Natural join is a bad recommendation under any circumstances (and it is not the right answer here).  `Natural join` is just a bug waiting to happen.